# File upload from windows popup using Robot class fails

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, file-import

I am using below code to select and import a csv file in my application.The file path gets pasted and I can also see the data getting imported, but still my test case fails and I am unable to figure out why.

```
public static void uploadFileFromFolder(String objectType, String objectName, String data) {
        // creating instance of Robot class
        try {
            StringSelection ss = new StringSelection(data);
            Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard().setContents(ss, null);
            // paste file path in windows pop-up
            Robot robot = new Robot();
            robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
            robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_V);
            robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_V);
            robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
            robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
            robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
        } catch (AWTException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

If sticking to Robot approach is not important, I would suggest you to handle file uploading this way:

```
// Find file input element
WebElement input = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input[type='file']"));

// Make sure element is visible
((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("arguments[0].style.display = 'block';", input);

// Specify you local file path here
input.sendKeys("/path/to/file/on/machine/which/runs/tests");
```

In case of RemoteDriver do not forget add this:

```
// Configure your client to upload local files to remote Selenium instance
    driver.setFileDetector(new LocalFileDetector());
```

NOTE: filepath should be absolute. You may make it in this way:

```
String getFilePath(String filePath) {
    new File(filePath).absolutePath
}
```

Comment: Please note, that this approach will work both in Windows and Linux

Comment: Hey @S. Plekhanov thanks. its not working. I get a invocationtargetexception

Comment: @user765, which line gives you an exception?